# Adding Pandas Column for iteration across MYSQL datatable

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append, multiple-columns

i have a list of symbols across which i run a query to return price data in a for loop. i want each query to return a new column appended to a dataframe.

```
stk_df = pd.read_sql("SELECT dt, close from futures WHERE symbol = 
'BANKNIFTY'AND dt >='" +st_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+"'AND dt <='" 
+d_t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+"'ORDER by dt ASC", db1)
stk_df = stk_df.set_index('dt')
query_cur.execute("SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM 
navposmod.futures a WHERE dt='2016-12-01') a, (SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM 
navposmod.`futures` b WHERE dt='2017-08-29') b WHERE a.symbol=b.symbol AND 
a.symbol NOT IN ('NIFTYINFRA','NIFTYIT','NIFTYMID50','NIFTYPSE')")
a = query_cur.fetchall()
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame()
print len(a)
print stk_df.ix[:,0]
for x in range(1,len(a)):
    symbol_str = a[x][0]
    print "processing for " + symbol_str
    stk_df1 = pd.read_sql("SELECT close from futures WHERE symbol = 
    +d_t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+"'ORDER by dt ASC", db1)
    #print stk_df1.ix[:,0]
    stk_df["'"+symbol_str+"'"] = stk_df1.ix[:,0]
    print stk_df
```

this returns a new column but is filled with nans

Comment: Please provide same indentation as in original file. If this is the same, then you must indent lines in for loop, so python knows it is in a loop.

Comment: i did. Sorry first time i am posting a question so didnt realise but have edited with indents. issue i am facing is when i print stk_df1.ix[:,0] i am returning a series of data but when i assign it to a dataframe column stk_df["'"+symbol_str+"'"] = stk_df1.ix[:,0] it fills the series with nans

Comment: ok nevermind figured it out. using stk_df["'"+symbol_str+"'"] = stk_df1['close'].values seems to do the trick

Comment: Great, I just came back from lunch and started explaining :D